# Any way to back up case history

Tags: history-tracking

Is there a way to backup case history? Most of our cases last longer than the 18 month case history retention timeframe we need to keep older entries for audit purposes. Is there any automated way to record history outside of salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce recently announced of giving provision to store history for more than 18 months. It might be better to have a look at that.

It is common to build custom history tracking with a custom history object and lookup to case object. Then populate data in this trigger using a trigger in case object.

I think there is no automated way to record history outside salesforce. You might have to develop some integration with external systems to achieve it.